# Tortoise SVN Icon Overlays Displaying Everywhere...Why?

Tags: windows-vista, tortoisesvn, mozy, file-icons

**Update:** So, this turns out to have nothing to do with Tortoise SVN. I use Mozy.com for off-site backups and their new version includes these icon overlays. They can be disabled via the config options...or see here http://forum.pcmech.com/showthread.php?p=1385433. Thanks @OS for the answer.

Been using Tortoise SVN for some time on my Vista box. Within the last few days (and after recently upgrading to 1.5.4) the icon overlays are displaying on all files.

My exclude path is:

*

My include paths are:

C:\Users\jw\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SVNProjects*

C:\Users\jw\Documents\VB Projects\SVNProjects*

I haven't touched those settings in months. Any ideas? Help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could add "Mozy" as a tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like that happened to me a few days ago and it turns out it's not related to Tortoise... I'm using Mozy to backup files automatically and their latest update includes icons very similar to Tortoise to mark backed-up files.

Comment: Bingo! I use Mozy and it updated just a few days ago. Thanks! Now how to turn it off...gonna dig through the Mozy settings.

Comment: Thank you for saving what was left of my sanity, dealing with the same misleading combination.

Answer (score 1):

Icons usually appear for folders for files in a folder that have a hidden *.svn* subfolder. It sounds like your icon cache is corrupt though. You might also want to check the *Icon Overlays* section in the *Settings* dialog. If it's using the default icon cache, try killing the TSVNCache.exe process. If it's using the chell cache, kill explore.exe, in a cmd window go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local`, type "`attrib –h IconCache.db`" and then "`del IconCache.db`" and re-start explorer.exe.

Comment: I killed the TSVNCache.exe process to no avail. Icons still showing the overlays. I've checked the Settings dialog as I mentioned in the question. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

The icons can disappear because there is a limit to the number of overlays Windows will support. 
See http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#ovlnotshowing

Answer (score 0):

agree with marxidad,

you can also try to rebuild the tortoisesvn icon cache using

> TortoiseProc.exe
>   /command:rebuildiconcache

from the command line.